# Can I determine if a reference to an Activity is valid?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

In the event that an `Activity` has been destroyed, but an `AsyncTask` still has a reference to the object, is there any way to directly query the referenced (destroyed) activity to determine if the `Activity` is still valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `onDestroy()` method of the Activity, set a flag to indicate that the Activity was destroyed.

Additionally, in the `AsyncTask` add a `WeakReference` to the `Activity` instead of a normal reference.

In the `onPostExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`, the Activity is still alive if the `WeakReference` still has a value, and the `Activity` itself still has the flag set to false.

Comment: I don't see any guarantee in the Android API that a weak reference to an Activity will guarantee to be persisted when the activity is valid and that the weak reference is guaranteed to be nullified when the Activity is destroyed. Do you have a specific reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: if the activity is freed , the weak reference will soon be nulled . such a thing should occur only after the activity was destroyed , since that's the last step of the activity lifecycle. of course , if there are still references to the activity, the flag i've written about will be used since the weak reference will still point to this activity . you can read about weakReference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html and about activity lifecycle here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: "will soon be nulled".. is not good enough. this does not give a good enough indication about the state of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping `WeakReference` to your activity.

```
WeakReference<Activity> ref = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
… … …
Activity activity = ref.get();
if (activity != null) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: I don't see any guarantee in the Android API that a weak reference to an Activity will guarantee to be persisted when the activity is valid and that the weak reference is guaranteed to be nullified when the Activity is destroyed.  Do you have a specific reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: To avoid duplication, see [complete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11834991/716075) by *android developer*.